# How to stratify data using Orange?

Tags: python, decision-tree, orange

Looking for some help from the Orange experts out there.

I have a data set of about 6 million lines.  For simplicity's sake, we'll consider only two columns.  One is of positive decimal numbers and is imported as a continuous value.  The other is of discrete values (either 0 or 1) where there is a ratio of 30:1 for 1's to 0's.

I am using a classification tree (which I label as 'learner') to get the classifier.  I'm then trying to do a cross-validation on my data set while adjusting for the overwhelming 30:1 sample bias.  I've tried several variations to do this but continue to get the same result regardless of whether I stratify the data or not.

Below is my code and I've commented out the various lines I've tried (using both True and False values for stratification):

```
import Orange
import os
import time
import operator

start = time.time()
print "Starting"
print ""

mydata = Orange.data.Table("testData.csv")

# This is used only for the test_with_indices method below
indicesCV = Orange.data.sample.SubsetIndicesCV(mydata)

# I only want the highest level classifier so max_depth=1
learner = Orange.classification.tree.TreeLearner(max_depth=1)

# These are the lines I've tried:
#res = Orange.evaluation.testing.cross_validation([learner], mydata, folds=5, stratified=True)
#res = Orange.evaluation.testing.proportion_test([learner], mydata, 0.8, 100, store_classifiers=1)
res = Orange.evaluation.testing.proportion_test([learner], mydata, learning_proportion=0.8, times=10, stratification=True, store_classifiers=1)
#res = Orange.evaluation.testing.test_with_indices([learner], mydata, indicesCV)

f = open('results.txt', 'a')
divString = "\n##### RESULTS (" + time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ") #####"
f.write(divString)
f.write("\nAccuracy:     %.2f" %  Orange.evaluation.scoring.CA(res)[0])
f.write("\nPrecision:    %.2f" % Orange.evaluation.scoring.Precision(res)[0])
f.write("\nRecall:       %.2f" % Orange.evaluation.scoring.Recall(res)[0])
f.write("\nF1:           %.2f\n" % Orange.evaluation.scoring.F1(res)[0])

tree = learner(mydata)

f.write(tree.to_string(leaf_str="%V (%M out of %N)"))
print tree.to_string(leaf_str="%V (%M out of %N)")

end = time.time()
print "Ending"
timeStr = "Execution time: " + str((end - start) / 60) + " minutes"
f.write(timeStr)

f.close()
```

Note:  There may seem like there are syntax errors (stratified vs. stratification) but the program runs as-is without exceptions.  Also, I know the documentation shows stuff like stratified=StratifiedIfPossible but for some reason, only boolean values work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where do you adjust for the 30:1 bias. If by stratification: no, stratification means the opposite (in some sense) of what you want: stratified sample is a sample in which the class distribution is roughly the same as in the "population". Therefore, by `stratified=True`, you tell Orange to make sure it keeps the 30:1 bias. If you don't stratify, the sample distribution may be randomly off a bit.

You probably wanted to do something along these lines:

```
# First, split the table into two tables with rows from different classes:

filt = Orange.data.filter.SameValue()
filt.position = -1
filt.value = 0
class0 = filt(mydata)
filt.value = 1
class1 = filt(mydata)

# Now class0 and class1 contain the rows from class 0 and 1, respectively
# Take 100 rows from each table:

sampler = Orange.data.sample.SubsetIndices2(p0=100)
ind = sampler(class0)
samp0 = class0.select(ind, 0)
ind = sampler(class1)
samp1 = class1.select(ind, 0)

# samp0 and samp1 now contain 100 rows from each class
# We have to merge them into a single table

balanced_data = Orange.data.Table(samp0)
balanced_data.extend(samp1)
```

After this, `balanced_data` will have 1:1 class ratio.

This may now be exactly what you want, though: this classifier will prefer the minority class too much, so its performance will be really bad. In my experience, you want to lower the 30:1 ratio, but not by too much.

Comment: This makes complete sense.  I had a feeling I was going down the wrong rabbit hole!

Comment: What does the value in your second line refer to (filt.position = -1)?  I understand that the position expects the index of feature in the Domain as returned by Orange.data.Domain.index but I don't know what the -1 means.

Comment: The class has index -1.

Otherwise, negative indices in Orange do not have the same meaning as in Python, which is an unfortunate design decision. But -1 is always the class.